# function countByExample mybatis-generator help me

Tags: mybatis, mybatis-generator, mybatis-mapper

I have a problem, in my picture. I use mybatis and countByExample method was generated by MyBatis Generator. Can u help me and see it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3arE.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOp1f.png

Comment: help me, see my picture

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't understand your question. Please elaborate. The best way to explain the problem is to create a small demo project with assertions like [these](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are reusing `jobCtrlExample` between method calls. if you do that, then you need to clear the previous conditions before you set new conditions. Probably adding this line will fix it:

```java
jobCtrlExample.clear();
```

It would be better to create a new example class for every method.